# Program to calculate MIN, MAX of array of elements where each element is of Map<String,Float>

Tags: java, collections

I have a array of elements where each element is of Map type

```
elements = [{"a":10,"b":12,"c":13,"d":14},{"a":2,"b":1,"c":5,"d":19},{"a":5,"b":4,"c":13,"d":4},{"a":140,"b":1,"c":4,"d":14}]
```

I want to find min max of Map Keys.

```
[{a "min": 2, "max": 140},{b "min": 1, "max": 5},{c "min": 4, "max": 13},{d "min": 4, "max": 19}]
```

My Approch is

```
    public class TestMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

ArrayList<Map<String, Float>> elements = new ArrayList<Map<String, Float>>();
System.out.println("Initial Mappings are: " + elements);

ArrayList<Float> A = new ArrayList<Float>();
ArrayList<Float> B = new ArrayList<Float>();
ArrayList<Float> C = new ArrayList<Float>();
ArrayList<Float> D = new ArrayList<Float>();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

Map<String, Float> elem = (Map<String, Float>) elements.get(i);

A.add(elem.get("a"));
B.add(elem.get("b"));
C.add(elem.get("c"));
D.add(elem.get("d"));
}
```

I have the written function to find Min and Max and call in the function

```
 System.out.println("A ->" + "Min: " + findMin(A) + " Max: " + findMax(A));
   System.out.println("B ->" + "Min: " + findMin(B) + " Max: " + findMax(B));
   System.out.println("C ->" + "Min: " + findMin(C) + " Max: " + findMax(C));
   System.out.println("D ->" + "Min: " + findMin(D) + " Max: " + findMax(D));
```

}

Is there any better way of doing this which is efficient.

Comment: Why not put the input in Map<String, List<Float>> elements.
So,you have => a:[1,2,4,6], b:[4,6,7,89]. here a is key and List of Float is value

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues in the code you've supplied, running it fails, but I think I got your meaning. See an example of min/max per each key in the sample code below.

```
ArrayList<Map<String, Float>> elements = new ArrayList<>();
elements.add(Map.of("a", (float) 10, "b", (float) 11));
elements.add(Map.of("a", (float) 12, "b", (float) 13));
elements.add(Map.of("a", (float) 14, "b", (float) 15));
System.out.println("Initial Mappings are: " + elements);

Map<String, Float> min = elements.stream().reduce((e1, e2) ->
        e1.keySet().stream()
                .map(k -> Map.of(k, Math.min(e1.get(k), e2.get(k))))
                .collect(HashMap::new, Map::putAll, Map::putAll)
).get();
Map<String, Float> max = elements.stream().reduce((e1, e2) ->
        e1.keySet().stream()
                .map(k -> Map.of(k, Math.max(e1.get(k), e2.get(k))))
                .collect(HashMap::new, Map::putAll, Map::putAll)
).get();
System.out.println(min);
System.out.println(max);
```

Comment: thanks for quick help

i am not able to compile this code getting syntex error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59419206/not-ablee-to-complile-this-code-syntax-error-on-token-elidedsemicolonandrig#comment105030430_59419206

Comment: Make sure you are using latest java compiler. In case you still get error, please share it